# Relationship between a categorical variable and a Bernoulli variable in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data

I would like to answer the following question:

What is the relationship between race and the likelihood of filing a state claim?

Race is a categorical variable but since the response (State_Claim_Made) is 0,1, I'm not exactly sure the best way to go about answering this question without a logistic model.

Below is my code for State_Claim_Made prediction over time (Convicted) which works perfectly.

```
ggplot(jail, aes(x=Convicted, y=State_Claim_Made)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", 
              method.args = list(family = "binomial"), 
              se = TRUE)
```

I am struggling however to translate this same idea to a categorical variable (Race) and it's relationship to the likelihood of filing a state claim (State_Claim_Made).

DATA SAMPLE:

```
structure(list(Last_Name = c("Banks", "Beamon", "Dandridge", 
"Deakle, Jr.", "Doyle", "Drinkard", "Ellis", "Embry", "Gaines", 
"Gurley", "Hinton", "Holemon", "Holsomback", "Hunt", "Jones", 
"Mahan", "Mahan", "McMillian", "Moore", "Padgett"), First_Name = c("Medell", 
"Melvin Todd", "Beniah Alton", "Evan Lee", "Robert E.", "Gary", 
"Andre", "Anthony", "Freddie Lee", "Timothy", "Anthony", "Jeffrey", 
"John", "H. Guy", "Lydia Diane", "Dale", "Ronnie", "Walter", 
"Daniel Wade", "Larry Randal"), Age = c("27", "24", "29", "59", 
"44", "37", "35", "23", "22", "22", "29", "23", "33", "54", "40", 
"22", "26", "45", "24", "40"), Race = c("Black", "Black", "Caucasian", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Black", "Black", "Black", 
"Caucasian", "Black", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
"Black", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Black", "Caucasian", "Caucasian"
), Sex = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male"), State = c("Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama"), CIU = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), Guilty_Plea = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), IO = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Worst_Crime = c(6, 1, 
1, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), Occurred = c(1999, 
1988, 1994, 2014, 1991, 1993, 2012, 1992, 1972, 1999, 1985, 1987, 
1987, 1987, 1997, 1983, 1983, 1986, 1999, 1990), Convicted = c(2001, 
1989, 1996, 2015, 1992, 1995, 2013, 1993, 1974, 2000, 1986, 1988, 
1988, 1993, 2000, 1986, 1986, 1988, 2002, 1992), Exonerated = c(2003, 
1990, 2015, 2015, 2001, 2001, 2014, 1997, 1991, 2002, 2015, 1999, 
2000, 1998, 2006, 1998, 1998, 1993, 2009, 1997), Sentence = c("15", 
"25", "Life", "Not sentenced", "20", "Death", "85", "20", "30", 
"35", "Death", "Life", "25", "Probation", "Life without parole", 
"35", "Life without parole", "Death", "Death", "Death"), Death_Penalty = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), DNA_Only = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), FC = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), MWID = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), F_MFE = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), P_FA = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), OM = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), ILD = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), State_Statute = c("Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), State_Claim_Made = c(0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 0), Zero_time = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Prem = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Pending = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Denied = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), State_Award = c("0", 
"0", "2", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Amount = c("0", "0", NA, "0", 
"129041.88", "0", "0", "0", "1000000", "0", NA, "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), `Non-Statutory_Case_Filed` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), No_Time = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Unfiled = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), Dismissed = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), Pending__1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Award = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), Premature = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Amount__1 = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "$ undisclosed", "0", "0"), Years_Lost = c(1.7, 
0.1, 19.5, 0, 2.6, 5.7, 1.8, 4, 10.7, 1.5, 28.5, 10.6, 10.1, 
0, 5.8, 11.4, 11.4, 4.5, 5.4, 5.5), State_Award2 = c("0", "0", 
"0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still use a logistic model with a categorical predictor:

```
g1 <- glm(State_Claim_Made ~ Race, family=binomial, data=jail)
summary(g1)
## Coefficients:
##                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
## (Intercept)   -2.056e-16  7.071e-01   0.000    1.000
## RaceCaucasian -6.931e-01  9.354e-01  -0.741    0.459
```

In this case the log-odds difference between baseline (Black) and
Caucasian is -0.693 (log-odds of State_Claim_Made is lower
for Caucasian), but not significantly <0. For a sample size this small, the results of a GLM need to be interpreted very cautiously ...

Or you can use a contingency table approach:

```
(tt <- with(jail, table(Race,State_Claim_Made))
##            State_Claim_Made
## Race        0 1
##   Black     4 4
##   Caucasian 8 4

chisq.test(tt, simulate.p.value=TRUE)
## data:  tt
## X-squared = 0.55556, df = NA, p-value = 0.6432
```

I prefer the GLM as it's more flexible and gives you an effect size, but the contingency table analysis might be preferred for simplicity (and accuracy for small sample sizes).

Comment: Hmmmm, I see what you did here but how exactly would the coefficients explain the relationship between a race and their individual liklihood to see state claims? @Ben_Bolker

Comment: Also, how do you justify doing a contingency table over an ANOVA test?